# Error : This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I saw lot of posts from stackoverflow regarding this but nothing succeeded.

Complete Error :

> It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.
>   This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured
>   as an application in IIS

Scenario:

I have a **root web.config** and **subdirectory web.config** in which **subdirectory web.config** contains

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

which creates the above problem.

I did the following,

1) I created a virtual directory in IIS and browse the application,It works fine

2) Initially had a backup folder and web.config due to VS updation, I removed Backup folder.

3) Checked any duplicate web.config inside Obj folder. Nothing found

4) Checked whether I opened via File -> Open -> Project/Solution. Its correct

5) Finally for testing, I commented the authentication part, now above error is over but new error indicates code behind of one of the aspx of the subdirectory is not found.

Any one faced this issue especially 5th point is different from other questions?

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is to take the web.config out of the subdirectory and configure the subdirectory access using the location attribute in the root level web.config.  Also, configure the subdirectory as an application by right clicking on it in IIS and selecting Create command.

Other ways are decribed here:  http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37609.aspx